# Splide slider: i am passing custom classes through options but it is removing default functionally of arrow

Tags: splidejs

This are the options i passed, i added `slider-prev` for previous same `slider-next` for next but not working

`options={{ type: 'slide', arrows: false, pagination: false, classes: { prev: 'slider-prev', next: 'slider-next', }, }}`

I tried this as well add `slider-arrow` common class here as well
`options={{ type: 'slide', arrows: false, pagination: false, classes: { prev: 'slider-arrow slider-prev', next: 'slider-arrow slider-next', }, }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, what you did it completely added custom classes for arrow and how this will work is, these classwa will totally replace with default splide slider classes. and to solve this or to add default css, you also need to pass that default class with your custom class.

```
classes: {
   arrows: 'splide__arrows your-class-arrows',
   arrow : 'splide__arrow your-class-arrow',
   prev  : 'splide__arrow--prev your-class-prev',
   next  : 'splide__arrow--next your-class-next',
 }
```

and For your case it will be like

```
classes: {
   prev: 'splide__arrow--prev slider-arrow slider-prev',
   next: 'splide__arrow--next slider-arrow slider-next',
}
```